# Modal CRUD Gii templates for Yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

Всем привет!
Кто нибудь пользовался этим генератоом?
Установил в web.php, прописал то что требуется, IP проставил:

```
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',      
        'allowedIPs' => ['109.254.254.62', '109.*'],  
        'generators' => [
            'modal_crud' => [ // generator name
                'class' => 'conquer\gii\templates\crud\Generator', // generator class
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

при запуске conquer/gii-modal выдает 404, что может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего надо прописать так conquer/gii/mod**e**l - для генерации файла модели

А для получения правильных ссылок необходимо перейти на главную страницу этого модуля site.test/gii

**UPD:** Не сразу заметил, что там в конфиге свой генератор. Для начала надо бы проверить, что работает дефолтный генератор без ошибок. А кастомный может быть с таким адресом заработает. conquer/gii/modal-crud

Comment: так тоже не получается

Comment: conquer/gii/modal-crud тоже самое, правда появилась ошибка в консоле:
http://star.popov.ints.net/debug/default/toolbar?tag=5b4cb4e7306f
он пытается дебаг запустить через ajax